Multiple Account Authorize in swagger ui of FastAPI
I created 'user' and 'shop' route respectively.
So there's an api where the 'user' account is accessible, and there's an api where the 'shop' account is accessible.
# user_route.py...
oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="/api/user/login")
router = APIRouter(
    prefix="/api/user",
)

# shop_route.py...
oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="/api/shop/login")
router = APIRouter(
    prefix="/api/shop",
)

However, only one type of account can be logged in in swagger ui.
So I thought about making swagger ui for 'user' and 'shop' router, respectively, but only 'app1' works
# main.py...
app1 = FastAPI(
    title="user Auth",
    docs_url="/docs-user"
)

app2 = FastAPI(
    title="user Auth",
    docs_url="/docs-shop"
)
...
app1.include_router(user_router.router)
app2.include_router(shop_router.router)

Is there a way to use both types of accounts in Swagger ui?

Does this help? - https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/sub-applications/

That's what I wanted, I managed to separate the swagger ui into two.
But it's still only one type of account to log in.
I'll have to check if there could be a problem with my code.
Thanks!

If I get you rigth, you try to achieve this behaviour:

You can use this code to achive this:
from typing import Annotated

from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends, FastAPI
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordBearer



application = FastAPI(
    title="TEST APP"
)


class ShopOAuth2PasswordBearer(OAuth2PasswordBearer):
    pass


class UserOAuth2PasswordBearer(OAuth2PasswordBearer):
    pass


# user_route.py...
oauth2_scheme_user = ShopOAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="/api/user/login")
router_user = APIRouter(
    prefix="/api/user",
)

# shop_route.py...
oauth2_scheme_shop = UserOAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="/api/shop/login")
router_shop = APIRouter(
    prefix="/api/shop",
)


@router_user.post("/login")
async def login_user(token: Annotated[str, Depends(oauth2_scheme_user)]):
    return {"token": "user_token"}


@router_shop.post("/login")
async def login_shop(token: Annotated[str, Depends(oauth2_scheme_shop)]):
    return {"token": "shop_token"}

application.include_router(router_user)
application.include_router(router_shop)

